# How can I use the distincted value of the result of inner join?

Tags: sql, oracle

**My goal** is to compare the result of code #1 with the in (since `=` is can't used) in the where clause.

Here is the code #1:

```
select distinct t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.teamname
from tblteam t1
inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = T4.SUBJECTSEQ
```

This results in 25 non-duplicate rows (this value is will sub query in where statement).

And, I'm going to use the result of #1 to use a subquery.

So I wrote the following code #2:

```
select t5.SUBJECTNAME, t3.SUBJECTEND, t1.TEAMSEQ
from tblteam t1
inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = T4.SUBJECTSEQ
where (t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.teamname) in (select distinct t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
                                      from tblteam t1
                                      inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
                                      inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
                                      inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
                                      inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
                                      inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = T4.SUBJECTSEQ);
```

But this result returns 150 rows.

I guess it's because `(t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.teamname)` in the where clause of the main query has a duplicate value. And a value of 150 is the same as the result of not applying distinct to select.

First, duplicate values ​​​came out by using `in` in the where clause,

I think that there is a duplicate value again because the `distinct` clause is gone in main query.

I'm curious about an approach that can solve this problem.

```
select t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
from tblteam t1
inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
inner join
    (select distinct subjectseq, teamname 
     from TBLSUBJECT, tblteam) t5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ;
```

This code returns 750 rows...

Below are answers to several questions.

> What's wrong with just select `t5.SUBJECTNAME, t3.SUBJECTEND, t1.TEAMSEQ` in the outer query?

The answer above is the problem is select distincted value is composed of a subquery and used as a condition of the where clause, and select distinct cannot be used in the main query.

> Have you already tried select distinct in the main query? What is the error ? If no errors what is the output and why it's wrong?

The answer above does not make sense to use distinct in the main query. Compare the result value of `select distinct t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.teamname` in the main query with the sub query of the where statement, and then the distinct value Because I want to compare , the same sentence as #2 code was created.

It seems that the `group by` syntax cannot be used because it does not get `t5.SUBJECTNAME, t3.SUBJECTEND, t1.TEAMSEQ`.

Also, the ERD is too complex to alter the table. So, I ask a question to find a way to solve this problem with a sql statement.

I would like to share my DB if possible, but I don't know how to share it.

best regards

here is all data sql (have to be opened with `UTF-8`

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ymJGAF5USx3HYK_5zf8aT7aLtQ__FPY/view?usp=sharing

output of inner and the complete query

```
TEAMSEQ,CLASSSEQ,TEAMNAME,CLASSSEQ,STUDENTSEQ,OPENCOURSESEQ,OPENCOURSESEQ,COURSESTATE,OPENSUBJECTREGISTER,STUDENTREGISTER,COURSESTART,COURSEEND,COURSESEQ,CLASSROOMSEQ,OPENSUBJECTSEQ,SUBJECTSTART,SUBJECTEND,AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ,OPENCOURSESEQ,AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ,TEACHERSEQ,SUBJECTSEQ,SUBJECTSEQ,SUBJECTNAME,PERIOD,BOOKSEQ
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question. But usually when I'm running some complex queries, I split them into small views. for example create view V1 as select * from Whatever, then create view V2 as select * from V1, etc... This way I can handle complex scenarios easilly. Of course this comes with a performance cost. But If you are not running Google or Facebook, who cares about 10ms more in execution time...

Comment: `DISTINCT` in the filter subquery makes no sense, because `IN` checks whether some value is a member of list or not, it cannot distinguish duplicate values and it doesn't matter. So what you've specified as distinct has nothing to do with the filtered result set. If you need a distinct values, add a `distinct` in the outer query or aggregate function over some of the fields. Or describe your requirements with more details, source data and desired output

Comment: *"I guess it's because (t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.teamname) in the where clause of the main query has a duplicate value."* That is not the cause.

Comment: Can you share the definition and sample data for `tblteam`?

Comment: You should use `teamseq` instead of `teamname` in predicate, team names could repeat on different seqs.
Check this: `SELECT teamname, count(1) FROM tblteam GROUP BY teamname`

Answer (score 0):

If you can share sample data for TBLTEAM and the results you expect to see I might be able to be more specific, but using what is in your all.sql and dummy values for TBLTEAM, I used the following query to narrow down the source of duplication:

```
select t3.availablesubjectseq, t1.teamname
     , count(*)
from   tblteam t1
       join tblclass t2 on t2.classseq = t1.classseq
       join tblopencourse t on t.opencourseseq = t2.opencourseseq
       join tblopensubject t3 on t3.opencourseseq = t.opencourseseq
group by t3.availablesubjectseq, t1.teamname
having count(*) > 1;
```

I got multiple rows for availablesubjectseq 46 (sample below - there were many more rows):

| AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ | TEAMNAME | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | Sixty-Two | 2 |
| 46 | Seventy | 2 |
| 46 | Seventy-Three | 2 |

Now to drill into that, I selected all the data for subject 46, and I can see that it it possible to have more than one subject for a course.

```
select *
from   tblteam t1
       join tblclass t2 on t2.classseq = t1.classseq
       join tblopencourse t on t.opencourseseq = t2.opencourseseq
       join tblopensubject t3 on t3.opencourseseq = t.opencourseseq
where t3.availablesubjectseq = 46
and   studentseq = 9;
```

The pattern looks like this (repeated for all students):

| TEAMSEQ | TEAMNAME | CLASSSEQ | CLASSSEQ | STUDENTSEQ | OPENCOURSESEQ | OPENCOURSESEQ | COURSESTATE | OPENSUBJECTREGISTER | STUDENTREGISTER | COURSESTART | COURSEEND | COURSESEQ | CLASSROOMSEQ | OPENSUBJECTSEQ | SUBJECTSTART | SUBJECTEND | AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ | OPENCOURSESEQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61 | Sixty-One | 61 | 61 | 9 | 3 | 3 | ??? | ?? | 30 | 29/03/2021 | 29/10/2021 | 10 | 2 | 30 | 17/07/2021 | 11/08/2021 | 46 | 3 |
| 61 | Sixty-One | 61 | 61 | 9 | 3 | 3 | ??? | ?? | 30 | 29/03/2021 | 29/10/2021 | 10 | 2 | 31 | 10/08/2021 | 16/08/2021 | 46 | 3 |

It's not clear what results you want to see, and I don't have all your test data, but perhaps this type of approach could help you trace the source of duplicated data when you join multiple tables.